# How to handle Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot error to take string on the graphs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

[image]                                          I am working on something like below for my project;

```
df =pd.DataFrame ({City: ['London', ‘Jakarta’, 'Newyork', 'Mumbai'],
‘Staff’: ['1000','2000','3000','4000']})
print (df.head())
df.plot(kind='line',x=’City’,y=’Staff’,color='red')
plt.show()
```

for this code I am getting an error as 
**TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot.**

Then I add below snippet:

```
df.Staff=pd.to_numeric(df.Staff)
```

but getting same error.
**Is there no way to take string on graph?**
OR do I need to redefine as;

```
x = ['London', ‘Jakarta’, 'Newyork', 'Mumbai']
y = ['1000','2000','3000','4000']
```

I checked for previous solutions but it is not looking something

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to incorrect data format you're entering. See an example below (note the `Staff` column, numeric, not a string as you enter):

```
df =pd.DataFrame ({'City': ['London', 'Jakarta', 'Newyork', 'Mumbai'],
                   'Staff': [1000,2000,3000,4000]})
df.plot(kind='line',x='City', y='Staff', color= 'red')
```

[image]

Should you still want to enter your numeric data as strings the following will help you:

```
df =pd.DataFrame ({'City': ['London', 'Jakarta', 'Newyork', 'Mumbai'],
                   'Staff': ['1000','2000','3000','4000']})

df['Staff'] = df['Staff'].astype("int") # astype("float")
df.plot(kind='line',x='City', y='Staff', color= 'red')
```

or even:

```
df =pd.DataFrame ({'City': ['London', 'Jakarta', 'Newyork', 'Mumbai'],
                   'Staff': ['1000','2000','3000','4000']})

df['Staff'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Staff'])
df.plot(kind='line',x='City', y='Staff', color= 'red')
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey ! It is working for me with plt.show(), but name of cities are not displaying on the graph. Any clue?                                                                                          Thanks & Regards!

Comment: Version of matplotlib?

Comment: Hi, Verson on mplb is 2.2.2

Comment: Well, mine is 3+ and it shows the city names, as you may see.

Comment: Well, actually I believe they are shown on the plot.... Try saving the image and opening in image editor or browser.

Comment: Hi, I did as you said in above comment but not done. I have updated it to 3.1.3 but yet same is the issue of not showing city names.

Comment: They are there, in grey on a greyish background.

Comment: Can you update your question with the image you're getting?

Comment: Done as discussed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208116/discussion-between-sergey-bushmanov-and-ads-kul).